# Module to extend object/table in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo

I want to extent a object / table and I have this error:

TypeError: The model "extended.project" specifies an unexisting parent class "project.phase" You may need to add a dependency on the parent class' module.

In **openerp**.py I put this depends:

```
'depends': ['base',"project","project_issue"],
```

In my_module.py I have this class:

```
class extended_project_pahse(osv.osv):
_name = "extended.project"
_inherit = "project.phase"
_columns = {
    'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company'),
}
_defaults = {
    'company_id': lambda self, cr, uid, ctx=None: self.pool.get('res.company')._company_default_get(cr, uid, 'project.task', context=ctx),
}
extended_project_pahse()
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

please add one more module name "project_long_term" in your dependency because the class "project.phase" is created here.

Vote For This

Answer (score 0):

you should add 'project_long_term' in your depends module list.

'depends': ['base',"project","project_issue","project_long_term"]

Answer (score 0):

in OpenERP 7 you don't need to instantiate model, and you must set the parent as osv.Model 
instead osv.osv

class extended_project_pahse(osv.Model):